# UIView layoutSubviews not being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Using Xcode 4.2/iOS5.0

I have a viewController and an associated viewController.xib. The viewController is set up as the .xib's file's owner. It is invoked from a `UINavigationController`.

I am attempting some manual layout when the device is rotated portrait/landscape

As I understand it the `UIView` method to override is

```
- (void)layoutSubviews;
```

this is where you do the layout

But - as with `drawRect` - you do not call this directly, it is invoked when appropriate by iOS

Instead you call `setNeedsLayout`...

So I have this in the ViewController

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)
         fromInterfaceOrientation {
   [[self view] setNeedsLayout];
 }
```

and  in the same ViewController I have this

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    //.manual override of automatic layout on rotation
NSLog(@"layoutSubviews");
 }
```

However `layoutSubviews` does not get called and I don't understand why.

Here is a clue... 
If I call `layoutSubviews` directly as `[self layoutSubviews]`

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)
         fromInterfaceOrientation {
   [self layoutSubviews];
 }
```

it does trigger

But if I call it as `[[self view] layoutSubviews]` it does not

So it appears that the view and it's controller are not wired up correctly?

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031292/layoutsubviews-only-called-once-despite-any-device-rotation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem here is you've implemented `-layoutSubviews` on your view controller, instead of on your view. It will never be called this way. `-layoutSubviews` is a mechanism by which a custom view can lay out its own subviews (e.g. a `UIButton` that has a `UIImageView` for the image and a `UILabel` for the label, and uses `-layoutSubviews` to ensure the imageview and label are all positioned correctly). It's not a mechanism by which a view controller can control the layout of its views.

If you want to change layout on rotation, then you should just go ahead and set up the new layout inside of `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your suggestion, it just works... I am quite new to this, still getting used to the relationship between views, controllers, models, apps.

Comment: Typo: -didRotateFormInterfaceOrientation: should be -didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: I tried to silently fix with a direct edit, but it was considered too trivial...

Answer (score 0):

For the general question, this also happens when you forget to call addSubview with your subview on the superview.