# layoutSubviews isn't called for UIView that has NIB-subviews with Auto Layout

Tags: iphone, layout, ios6, uiview, nib

I work with iOS 6. I created a custom sub-class of `UIView` that has my own layout logic described in overridden `layoutSubviews` method. I expect to support both Portrait and Landscape modes so invocation of `layoutSubviews` is critical for me. I re-arange and resize sub-views programmatically inside `layoutSubviews` without using any constraints.

Everything works fine if I operate with simple controls or UIViews added as sub-views into my custom sub-class. But if I add at least one NIB-based sub-view that has Auto Layout with some constraints then `layoutSubviews` is never called on rotation in my sub-class and therefore I can't update the layout.

This is probably something very simple, but I couldn't find the solution here and since I am new to iOS can't figure by myself. Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to rearrange the subviews when the device is rotated? If so you should register for device rotation notifications and adjusts your subviews when the rotation is detected.

Comment: Since I work with a sub-class of UIView I can't override  `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method, because it's a part of UIViewController class. Anyway, the problem is not with listening of rotation notifications, the problem is that `layoutSubviews` isn't called if there are NIB sub-views with Auto Layout in my custom sub-class.

Comment: This worked for me
`override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
     // you can get updated frame etc
    }
 }
 `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seemed to be much deeper than I expected. I spent two days doing debugging and reading about all this stuff with mixing Auto Layout and Autoresize layout approaches and eventually I figured that it's really hard to combine some views with Auto Layout and to have some intermediate views with programmatic layout.

I temporary fixed mentioned problem by just manually calling `layoutSubviews` and setting `Frame` of my custom sub-class of UIView in the super's `layoutSubviews` method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I think you have the same issue where the `layoutSubviews` is not being called altogether. Please check the following links and see :-

[When is layoutSubviews called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/when-is-layoutsubviews-called)

[UIView layoutSubviews not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192072/uiview-layoutsubviews-not-being-called)

["Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews" with UITableViewCell subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610783/auto-layout-still-required-after-executing-layoutsubviews-with-uitableviewcel)

These questions are similar to your issue . Hope they help.

Comment: Well, thanks for the links. I've seen some of them already and after reviewing the rest so far I was not able to extract a solution :-/